# EJB wraps all Exceptions into EJBException

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Assuming I have a **@Stateless** bean:

```
@Local
public interface A {
    public void check() throws MyException {
}

@Stateless
public class AImpl implements A {
    public void check() throws MyException {
        ...
        try {
            data = getDataFromService();
        } catch (RException e) {   
            throw new MyException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
public class MyException extends Exception{}
public class RException extends RuntimeException{}
```

When I am injecting this bean to some other class with the use of **@EJB** annotation and executing the *check()* method, I am getting **EJBException** with **MyException** as its cause...

```
public class B {
    @EJB private A a;
    public void start() {
        try {
            a.check();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it throw proper exception?

Any ideas how to make it work ok?

Is there any way to make it work without intercepting the **EJBException** throw, and rethrowing its exception cause?

Comment: This sounds like a defect. If the interface has `throws Exception` and `MyException extends Exception`, then it should it should be rethrown as-is by the EJB container, not wrapped in an `EJBException`.

Comment: which version of jboss?

Comment: have you applied any interceptor around your method call? and a try/catch around the invocationContext.proceed method? and rethrow a RuntimeException instead of the originally catched exception?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume your `MyException`extends `RuntimeException` and therefore it is unchecked exception. in such case you can annotate your exception with `@ApplicationException` annotation. As a result of that your exception will be an application exception instead of a system exception. When a system exception is thrown it is packaged in EJBException, but application exceptions are thrown directly to the client.

Comment: Not exacly true - the proper usecase differs a little: I have RException which is thrown, i catch it and then I throw MyException with init exception wrapped, but MyException is not Runtime... It is checked... Still, I will try with this annotation as it may be the good approach:)

Comment: In example code you presented above there is no exception rethrown and I cannot see that RuntimeException is thrown. Basically I think you should update the example with situation you are thinking about.

Comment: added some more snipets